# Initializing class member vector with size fails

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, vector

I'm new with c++ and came across to this problem. Here is my code:

```
class A
{
    std::vector <int> vec(10);
};
```

It gives me error saying `expected a type specifier`. I know that this way of initializing a vector is not acceptable and it should be done in constructor but I'm curious why this fails. I also noticed that this:

```
class A
{
    std::vector <int> vec = std::vector<int>(10);
};
```

Works perfectly fine.

So my question is why does second case work even though we are still creating vector with "predefined size"(`std::vector<int>(10)`), and why does the first case fail? thanks.

**P.S**
I'm trying to create vector with size for 10 ints, not create a vector with with `10` already inserted in it.

Comment: C++11 or above? use `{20}` instead of `(20)`. You declared a function which takes a syntax error and returns a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Thanks you for you reply. I was trying to create a vector with allocated memory for 6 members, will `{20}` do the same?

Comment: This is not a most vexing parse error. This is a variable definition, but in a place it is not allowed.

Comment: @mch For `vector`, as it has initializer_list constructor so they are not same. `vector<int>(20)` : 20 elements with value of 0. `vector<int>{20}` : just one elemnt with value of 20.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen No it's not. A function declaration cannot have an integer literal in place of its argument list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### What?

Since C++11 we have [non-static data member initialisers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members), making this approach to initialising members completely valid. **However, you *must* use either `=` or `{}`.**

<sup>Formally, if an initializer is present here, [it must be](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem) with a [*brace-or-equal-initializer*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#nt:brace-or-equal-initializer) grammatical production.</sup>

Since you've instead used a syntax that doesn't count as initialisation here, the compiler tries to make a function declaration out of `vec`, which breaks because `20` is not a type.

---

#### Why?

The chapter named "Problem 1" in the original feature proposal ([N2756](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm)) explains that `()` was disallowed here to avoid some confusion with respect to member function declarations.

The author does note therein that the committee *could* have let it be, and had it work like other declarations — that is, it's a function if it can be, and an object otherwise*. But the author decided to go a different direction and just ban the syntax to avoid the problem in this particular case.

> **Unfortunately, this makes initializers of the “( *expression-list* )” form ambiguous at the time that the declaration is being parsed** *[..]*
>
> **One possible solution is to rely on the existing rule that, if a declaration could be an object or a function, then it’s a function** *[..]*
>
> A similar solution would be to apply another existing rule, currently used only in templates, that if `T` could be a type or something else, then it’s something else; and we can use “`typename`” if we really mean a type *[..]*
>
> **Both of those solutions introduce subtleties that are likely to be misunderstood by many users** (as evidenced by the many questions on comp.lang.c++ about why “`int i();`” at block scope doesn’t declare a default-initialized `int`).
>
> **The solution proposed in this paper is to allow only initializers of the “= *initializer-clause*” and “{ *initializer-list* }” forms.** That solves the ambiguity problem in most cases.

Such is life.

---

#### So?

> I'm trying to create vector with size for 10 ints, not create a vector with with 10 already inserted in it.

This is an important point. Be careful, because initialising a vector with `{}` [won't do that](https://medium.com/@barryrevzin/uniform-initialization-isnt-82533d3b9c11). "Uniform" initialisation unfortunately [merely added more meanings](https://xkcd.com/927/). So much for solving the ambiguity problem…

You should therefore use either the `=` syntax, or just do this in the constructor (my favourite).

---

<sub>* This is where the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) can sometimes bite you, though not every occurrence of unintended function declarations is an example of the most vexing parse.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation :)

Comment: @user3503143 You're welcome! I didn't know this, so learnt something also.

Answer (score 1):

It's not well written. You can use the following example as well. Here, i'll leave the vector empty, but `reserve()` space for 20 pointers, so you can insert without having to reallocate. A more simple and better solution (with a constructor) would be:

A.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

A::A()
{
   this->vec.reserve(20);
   std::cout << "Setting size" << std::endl;
}
A::~A()
{
}
```

A.hpp

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP_

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
        A();
        ~A();
        std::vector<int> vec;
};

#endif /* !A_HPP_ */
```

main.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

int main()
{
   A a;
}
```

Output:

```
Setting size
```

And your vector size is done.

Comment: It's not in the wrong place, and it is allowed, it's just written invalidly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to declare and initialize a member variable with the syntax `type name(value);`, but you can with `type name{value};` or `type name = value;`.

This is the syntax from the Standard:

> `[class.mem]/1`
>
> ```
> member-declaration:
>   attribute-specifier-seq(opt) decl-specifier-seq(opt) member-declarator-list(opt);
>   [...]
> member-declarator-list:
>   member-declarator
>   member-declarator-list , member-declarator
> member-declarator:
>   [...]
>   declarator brace-or-equal-initializer(opt)
>   [...]
> ```

And

> `[dcl.init]/1`
>
> ```
> brace-or-equal-initializer:
>   = initializer-clause
>   braced-init-list
> braced-init-list:
>   { initializer-list , (opt) }
>   { designated-initializer-list , (opt) }
>   { }
> ```

So the following:

```
class C
{
    int a = 0;
    int b{0};
}
```

is valid.

The definition of `C::a` is a *member-declaration* with a *member-declarator-list* composed of a single member initialized with a *brace-or-equal-initializer* of the form `= initializer-clause`.

Similarly, `C::b` uses the form *braced-init-list*.

On the other hand, you'll find no syntax for `int c(0);`.