# error: expected ';', ',' or ') before numeric constant

Tags: c++, class, stack

I am making a stack class, and trying to make an object of it and using it in another class. However, it mentions that there is an error.
here's my code of intializing the stack object in the class:

```
class functions{
public:
int m[5];
int c=0;
stack_x mem(5);
```

Comment: What's `stack_x`? What's `mem`? What's `mem(5);` doing outside of a function? Where is the rest of your class and your program?

Comment: Where is curly bracket `};` that closes the class declaration?

Comment: already written but in the very end of the class, i just posted the part which making the error

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54590838/560648. See my answer there.

Answer (score 7):

You can't initialise members using parentheses in the class definition.
Use curly braces — `stack_x mem{5};`.

Comment: Some more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54591052/560648

Comment: "Use curly braces" - or `=`. `stack_x mem = 5;`

Comment: stack_x is a stack class with a maximum size of 5, the stack class is implemnted using array, so i do it with []. when I put {}, the error is gone, however, am not sure that it will work properly as intended to?

Answer (score 0):

If the previous class (stack_x) looks like an custom class its correctly closed

```cpp
class stack_x
{
 // Class definition
}; // MUST BE

class functions
{
// Class definition
};
```

Comment: I did so, but still not works, i only copied the part of intialzing the object of stack_x class in functions class